# Vue js & validate DOB is within a range?

Tags: validation, vue.js

Using Vue js and v-validate how can I determine if the date of birth is greater than 21 and less then 55 years old? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You probably need to bring [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) into the picture.

Comment: Currently I am using var formatedDate = moment(this.Month + '-' + this.Day + '-' + this.Year).format(dateFormat) to get the date as a string. I need to show in line validation error if the user input is not in range. Something like : v-validate="'{input > 21 || input < 55}"

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as moment from "moment";

let birthday = moment(moment.now()).diff(moment(this.user.day + this.user.month + this.user.year, "DD.MM.YYYY"),"years");
if(birthday > 21 && birthday < 55) {
  // do next steps
}
```

Moment(`npm install moment`) is used to parse, manipulate & display dates and times in JavaScript. `moment.now()` will give the present date and assuming you have three fields for `day`, `month` and `year` in different variables, format it and use the `diff` function to find the age.

Answer (score 0):

The example from Madhuri works for me but i change the input as hard coded string.

```
enter code here let birthday = moment(moment.now()).diff(moment('01.01.1990', "DD.MM.YYYY"), "years");
          if(birthday >= 20 && birthday <=70 ){
            return birthday;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with with value from form input which works for me.

```
checkBirthday(){
          const birthDayDate = document.getElementById("birthdate").value;
          const age = moment().diff(birthDayDate, "years");
          // let birthday = moment(moment.now()).diff(moment('01.01.1990', "DD.MM.YYYY"), "years");
          if(age >= 18 && age <=74 ){
            return age;
          }
        },
```